# Ling adder vs classic CLA adder what's the difference?

Tags: vhdl, computer-architecture, adder

I'm practicing in designing vhdl unit with some "complex" computer arithmetic algorithm.
I've just implemented the following CLA unit below.

[image]

I'm reading through [this book](http://hron.fei.tuke.sk/~adam/aps/preklad/1999%20Computer%20arithmetic-Algorithms%20and%20hardware%20designs.pdf), page section 6.3 page 97, I want to implement the Ling adder. I'm not sure however whether I've understood correctly or not the problem.

With reference to the book notation, basically the idea is to compute instead of $$
\begin{array}{l}
c_{i+j} = \sum_{k=0}^{j} g_{i+k} \prod_{l=k+1}^{j} p_l + c_i\prod_{l=0}^{j} p_j \\
p_{[i,i+j]} = \prod_{k=0}^{j} p_{i+j} \\
g_{[i,i+j]} = \sum_{k=0}^{j} g_{i+k} \prod_{l=k+1}^{j} p_l
\end{array}
$$

I need to implement as basic block one who would compute the quantities

$$
h_i = c_i + c_{i-1},t_{[i,i+j]}, g_{[i,i+j]}
$$

and instead of "xoring" the propagation with the carries I'd have to compute a slightly more complex function, is this the only difference in terms of implementation? A similar hierarchical design I suppose could be applied.

Comment: Lol, I have this book in front of me as I am reading this question. May I ask why you want to do this in VHDL? I will likely not improve FPGA, as they already implement optimal carry chain logic.

Comment: Why the "Lol"? I've been taught that the best way to learn something is do it.

Comment: The lol because it is a coincidence that I have this book by Parhami right in front of me as I am reading this question. I used this book when I was in university 12-13(!) years ago, and coincidentally took it off the shelf last week.

Comment: Ah ok xD. Were you reading that specific part? That would be a huge coincidence. Anyway I want to see how the synthesis would vary by varying some parameters of that design.

Comment: But still: why are you using VHDL? Just for simulation or for FPGA synthesis? The latter will work, but not give the expected performance, since the function is implemented in LUTs. And did you google "ling adder" already? You get some good hits, like [this](https://www.ece.cmu.edu/~ee760/760docs/mcfarland-ling-adder.pdf)

Comment: Well simulation to see if I've understood the algorithm (sometimes it's just for pleasure of reviewing stuff), but I'm going to synthesize later (not FPGA). I've also seen the document you forwarded, but to be honest I prefer that book since it has been my main reference for this stuff.

Comment: No I was reading about floating point multipliers.

Comment: http://web.archive.org/web/20060630021602/http://www.research.ibm.com/journal/rd/252/ibmrd2502a3I.pdf Also see http://web.archive.org/web/20060410222424/http://lap.epfl.ch/courses/comparith/Papers/9-Nafziger-Ling-Adder.pdf

Comment: Is the first one the original paper?